# Calculating highs, lows, and volumes of stocks

Tags: c++, performance, finance

I'm trying to review and figure the issues in the above code. Any inputs to point out problems are welcome.

```
using namespace std;
typedef basic_string<char> string;

class   CHighLow
{
public:
    CHighLow() : nCurLow(0), nCurHigh(0) {};

    void    add(int nHigh, int nLow)
    {
        if (nHigh > nCurHigh)
            nCurHigh = nHigh;

        if (nLow < nCurLow)
            nCurLow = nLow;
    }

    int     nCurLow;
    int     nCurHigh;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (!strcmp("version", argv[1]))
    {
        cerr << "Using version 1.0 VWAPer" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    FILE*   file = fopen(argv[2], "r");

    cerr << "Reading file" << argv[2] << endl;

    char    line[256];
    char    Stocks[1000][10];
    int     Intervals[1000];
    int     Volumes[1000];
    float   Highs[1000];
    float   Lows[1000];

    int     i = 0;
    int     sum = 0;

    while (fgets(line, 256, file))
    {
        sscanf(line, "%s %d %d %f %f", 
Stocks[i], &Intervals[i], 
&Volumes[i], &Highs[i], &Lows[i++]);

        cerr << Stocks[i] << endl;
        cerr << Intervals[i] << endl;
        cerr << Volumes[i] << endl;
        cerr << Highs[i] << endl;
        cerr << Lows[i] << endl;
    }

    cerr << "Calculating total volumes" << endl;

    map<std::string, int>       TotalVolumes;

    for (int s = 0; s <= i; ++s)
    {
        std::string stockname = Stocks[s];

        for (int j =0; j <= i; ++j)
        {
            if (!strcmp(Stocks[j], stockname.c_str()))
            {
                TotalVolumes[stockname] += Volumes[j];
            }
        }
    }

    cerr << "Calculating high lows" << endl;

    map<std::string, CHighLow>  HighLows;

    for (int s = 0; s <= i; ++s)
    {
        HighLows[Stocks[s]].add(Highs[s], Lows[s]);
    }

    cerr << "Writing files" << endl;

    // write file a
    for (int s = 0; s <= i; ++s)
    {
        cout << Stocks[s] << "," << Intervals[s] << "," << 
TotalVolumes[Stocks[s]] / Volumes[s] * 100 << endl;
    }

    // write file b
    map<std::string, CHighLow>::iterator itr = HighLows.begin();
    while (itr != HighLows.end())
    {
        cout << (*itr).first << "," << (*itr).second.nCurLow << "," << 
(*itr).second.nCurHigh << endl;

        ++itr;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Do not [`using namespace std`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: Ok, So how does that affect the code?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Code Review. Please add more context to the question, such as explain what your code does and your major concerns.

Comment: @Sammy click the link and find out.

Comment: can you use a c++11 or c++14 compiler? And what are the issues you mentioned

Comment: Does the code work as intended? Does it give the correct results?

Answer (score 3):

**First, the obvious ones:**

1. Change `nCurLow` and `nCurHigh` to `float`s since you are reading `float` from file.
2. Change

   ```
   nCurLow(0)
   ```

   to

   ```
   nCurLow(std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity())
   ```

   and

   ```
   nCurHigh(0)
   ```

   to

   ```
   nCurHigh(-std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity())
   ```

   because initializing min/max with 0 can lead to bugs if values are all >0 or <0.
3. Drop `typedef basic_string<char> string;` and use `std::string` instead.
4. Check `argc` if you have arguments before you use `argv` (prevents crash when invalid arguments are passed).
5. Don't use `cerr` only when you want to report error, use `std::cout` instead.
6. Don't increment `i` like this: `... &Lows[i++]);`. In fact drop those arrays all together and use `std::vector`, and `std::string` instead (because that while so broken in so many ways ...).
7. The iteration looks bogus, `for (int s = 0; s <= i; ++s)` because of `<=` so change it to [ranged-based `for`s](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for).
8. Avoid `stdcmp`; use [`operator==`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp) from `std::string`.

These points only refer to potential errors and bugs.

**Now for the less obvious ones:**

1. I see a comment `//write to a file`. `std::cout` does not write to file but to standard output. use [file streams](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream) if writing to a file is the intended behavior
2. This code:

   ```
   for (int s = 0; s <= i; ++s)
   {
       std::string stockname = Stocks[s];

       for (int j =0; j <= i; ++j)
       {
           if (!strcmp(Stocks[j], stockname.c_str()))
           {
               TotalVolumes[stockname] += Volumes[j];
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   What does it actually do? It looks totally inefficient. The obvious thing is that `TotalVolumes[stockname]` can be evaluated only once. The second is that `j` can be equal to `s`.
3. The rest of the code seems to make excessive use of memory. It looks like it can be simplified a lot, with fewer iterations, less memory usage, less confusion.
4. It would be nice if there would be some comments to describe what the code actually does.
5. `return 1` in `main`. If this will be used in an automated tool return 1 might mean that an error has occurred. Change it to `return 0` and `return 1` only when an actual error has happened (invalid argument, file not found, corrupted file data, etc).
6. More error checking.

There could be other things, but having some test data would be nice. There could be soft bugs in the code.

Answer (score 1):

This code doesn't catch any buffer overflows.
What happens e.g. if

- the file contains more than 1000 lines
- a line is more than 256 characters long
- the name of a stock more than 10
- the number of command line parameters is less than 2

And if I'm not completely mistaken, then

```
for (int s = 0; s <= i; ++s)
{
    std::string stockname = Stocks[s];

    for (int j = 0; j <= i; ++j)
    {
        if (!strcmp(Stocks[j], stockname.c_str()))
        {
            TotalVolumes[stockname] += Volumes[j];
        }
    }
}
```

can be replaced by

```
for (int s = 0; s <= i; ++s)
{
    TotalVolumes[Stocks[s]] += Volumes[s];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Suggestion 1**

The line

```
    sscanf(line, "%s %d %d %f %f", 
           Stocks[i], &Intervals[i], 
           &Volumes[i], &Highs[i], &Lows[i++]);
```

is not right. `i++` can be executed first, last, or anywhere in between. The standard does not specify the order of evaluation of arguments.

Also, you are incrementing `i` in that statement followed by:

```
    cerr << Stocks[i] << endl;
    cerr << Intervals[i] << endl;
    cerr << Volumes[i] << endl;
    cerr << Highs[i] << endl;
    cerr << Lows[i] << endl;
```

which will print the values using an index that is off by one.

I would recommend converting the `while` loop to a `for` loop:

```
for ( i = 0; fgets(line, 256, file); ++i)
{
    sscanf(line, "%s %d %d %f %f", 
           Stocks[i], &Intervals[i], 
           &Volumes[i], &Highs[i], &Lows[i]);

    cerr << Stocks[i] << endl;
    cerr << Intervals[i] << endl;
    cerr << Volumes[i] << endl;
    cerr << Highs[i] << endl;
    cerr << Lows[i] << endl;
}
```

This resolves both issues.

**Suggestion 2**

The member function `CHighLow::add` seems a misnomer to me. What's being "added" in the function? A better name would be `CHighLow::update`. I would go further and create two functions `updateHigh` and `updateLow`.

```
  void updateHigh(int nHigh)
  {
     if (nHigh > nCurHigh)
        nCurHigh = nHigh;
  }

  void updateLow(int nLow)
  {
     if (nLow < nCurLow)
        nCurLow = nLow;
  }
```

That is probably my personal preference to keep functions as simple as possible and build from there.

**Suggestion 3**

Use of `i` to store the number of entries in the file seems a strange choice. Most of us are used to using `i` as a looping variable. I would recommend using `numEntries` or `numRecords` instead of `i` for keeping track of the number of entries in the file.